# Android Keyboard fix orientation

Tags: android, keyboard, orientation, android-softkeyboard

I have a Android Keyboard like a SoftKeyboard and I want to fix the screen in portrait orientation when the keyboard is activated, so, use the keyboard with the editTExt of the app just in portrait (I have just the keyboard, no the app).

Comment: question is not clear?

Comment: Sorry, I just want lock the orientation in portrait when the keyboard is activated, lock all the screen (the app and the keyboard; app is anyone: whatsapp, fb, msg.., keyboard is mine, my development)